# How to perform database operation independently?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, serial-port

I have `1 exe` which is nothing bit a `Windows form` which will continuously run in background and will `watch my serial port` and I have 1 event `data receive event which fires as my serial port receive data`.

As soon as I receive data in this event I will pass this data to another event handler which `saves this data in database through web api method`.

But data to my serial port will be coming frequently so I want to save this data to my database independently so that my database insert operation doesn't block my incoming serial port data.

This is my code:

```
void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)//Fires as my serial port receives data
{
    int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
    int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
    if (nbrDataRead == 0)
        return;

    // Send data to whom ever interested
    if (NewSerialDataRecieved != null)
    {
        NewSerialDataRecieved(this, new SerialDataEventArgs(data)); //pass serial port data to new below event handler.
    }
}


void _spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataEventArgs e) //I want this event handler to run independently so that database save operation doenst block incoming serial port data
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Using this.Invoke causes deadlock when closing serial port, and BeginInvoke is good practice anyway.
        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(_spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved), new object[] { sender, e });
        return;
    }
    //data is converted to text
    string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
            //This is where i will save data to through my web api method.
            RunAsync(str).Wait();
    }
}

static async Task RunAsync(string data)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:33396/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var content = new StringContent(data);
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<StringContent>("api/Service/Post", content);//nothing happens after this line.
    }
}
```

Web api controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var someText = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = new StringContent(someText) };
    }
}
```

But here problem is:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<StringContent>("api/Service/Post", content);
```

Nothing happens after this line that is operation blocks on this line.

So can anybody guide me with this?

Comment: OK, I can see that you start asking using the site's Q&A again and not by personal chats to multiple people at the same time, upvoted.

Comment: @Ian:Any help or suggestions??

Comment: You probably could have a background thread to do that. When you receive data from serial port, you put that in a `Queue` or `List` or `Stack` - any collection type which fits your need, and you also have the `background thread` which checks the existence of the item in that collection periodically. You use this thread to store to the database independently.

Comment: @Ian:Any example or any reference from where i can get this or it would be more better if you can post the code

Comment: There isn't any for your particular case. But if you search little by little, I think you should find how people normally do that by looking at the keyword one by one: background thread, queue, stack, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By independently we determined in the SO C# chat room that you really mean "Asynchronously".

Your solution is the code above, saving this data to a WebAPI endpoint so any solution to the problem needs to be in 2 parts ...

PART 1: The Client Part

On the client all we need to do is make the call asynchronously in order to free up the current thread to carry on receiving data on the incoming serial port, we can do that like so ...

```
// build the api client, you may want to keep this in a higher scope to avoid recreating on each message
var api = new HttpClient();
api.BaseAddress = new Uri(someConfigVariable);

// asynchronously make the call and handle the result
api.PostAsJsonAsync("api/My", str)
    .ContinueWith(t => HandleResponseAsync(t.Result))
    .Unwrap();
```

...

PART 2: The Server Part

Since you have web api i'm also going to assume you are using EF too, the common and "clean" way to do this, with all the extras stripped out (like model validation / error handling) might look something like this ...

```
// in your EF code you will have something like this ...
Public async Task<User> SaveUser(User userModel)
{
   try
  {
      var newUser = await context.Users.AddAsync(userModel);
      context.SavechangesAsync();
      return newUser;
  }
  catch(Exception ex) {}
}

// and in your WebAPI controller something like this ...

HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(User newUser)
{
     return Ok(await SaveUser(newUser));
}
```

...

Disclaimer:

The concepts involved here go much deeper and as I hinted above, much has been left out here like validation, error checking, ect but this is the core to getting your serial port data in to a database using the technologies I believe you are using.

Key things to read up on for anyone wanting to achieve this kind of thing might include: Tasks, Event Handling, WebAPI, EF, Async operations, streaming.

Comment: There will be slight changes in your code.First there is no such method like:AddAsync and second the await will come on await will comes with SavechangesAsync

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe it seems like you might want to have a setup like this:
1) your windows form listens for serial port
2) when new stuff comes to port your windows forms app saves it to some kind of a queue (msmq, for example)
3) you should have separate windows service that checks queue and as it finds new messages in a queue it sends request to web api

Comment: You are right but should i go for windows service or backgroud thread will do the job??

Comment: well, that pretty much depends on you. you have several options, user Ian already mentioned some. you can definitely do it in background thread of windows forms app but then again, you are tight coupling database saving to windows forms app life-cycle/crash/error/etc. again, it might not be a problem for you but its a notion to be taken into account. on the other hand, you could go without explicit background threads but instead make use of task parallel library and async datababase saving. if i were you, i would go with windows service and a queue of some kind.

Comment: your NewSerialDataRecieved event handler is not market as async + you have runasasync.wait() which makes it wait/block the caller. you need to have async/await all the way down if you want it to be truly async.

Comment: Ok so as per your suggestion i will use window service but what i should use queue or BlockingCollection<stat>  as per this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839461/executing-event-at-regular-interval-with-net-4-5

Comment: leave windows service aside for now. please read my comment above about async/await. once you solve that one then you can move to next step of decoupling db save from windows forms app.

Comment: Ok so i will marked this NewSerialDataRecieved event handler as async right

Comment: this one might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406901/task-parallel-library-code-freezes-in-a-windows-forms-application-works-fine-a

Answer (score 1):

Best solution for this problem is to use ConcurrentQueue.
Just do search on google and you will get planty of samples.
ConcurrentQueue is thread safe and it support writing and reading from multiple threads.
So the component listening to the searal port can write data to the queue. And you can have 2 or more tasks running parallel which listening to this queue and update db as soon as it receives data.

Comment: See this which suggest BlockingCollection:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839461/executing-event-at-regular-interval-with-net-4-5

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the problem, but you shouldn't block on async code. You are doing `RunAsync(str).Wait();` and I believe that's the problem. Have a look at this blog post by Stephen Cleary:
 http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html